# Keep getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I keep getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, whenever I'm done picking a picture

[image]

Edited version
the value of image is there

[image]

Update2

[image]

Comment: In swift you can have semicolons or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add your image view to your view controller then you will see your output. Currently you are not able to see your output because you didn't added this image view to your view. So please do

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        imagePicked = UIImageView()
        imagePicked.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)

        self.view.addSubview(imagePicked);
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imagePicked!.image = image
}
```

this is happening because you are assign image without allocation of your imagePicked.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: tried it, and whenever I click a picture, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't even close the gallery.

Comment: @sinusGob Now please my whole method it also dismiss the view.

Comment: I use exactly this one. but same result, what would be the problem here?

Comment: I get a lot of errors when implementing your new code , for example **Cannot find an initializer for type UIImageView**

Comment: @sinusGob Now please see it. hope it will help you.

Comment: Tried your code, but still get errors, check my update2 picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78401/discussion-between-dharmbir-choudhary-and-sinusgob).

Answer (score 0):

The first error you get is because your `imagePicked` in not initialised, and you are assigning an Image to it.

Solution to this problem is simply initialise it. Use the following code either in `viewdidLoad` or 
`imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`

```
imagePicked = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Remember to dismiss the imagePicker using the following code

```
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

To make the image visible add the image view in your case `imagePicked` to the view. To do so add the following code after you dismiss the imagePicker

```
imagePicked.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) // Use values that you need
self.view.addSubview(imagePicked)
```

Your 
`imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` should look like this

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imagePicked = UIImageView(image: info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
    imagePicked.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)  // whatever frame you want
    self.view .addSubview(imagePicked)
}
```

> **Note:** 
>   **`- imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

imagePicked is nil.   You declare it at the top ( `var imagePicked : UIImageView!`).  The exclamation says "hey, this won't be nil, I promise."  So you silence all compile warnings and errors, but... You never instantiate it, so you break the promise.

In did finish picking image with info do:

```
   if imagePicked == nil {
         //init and configure your imageView
         imagePicked = UIImageView(...)
   }

   //you can safely use it here...
```

At the top change the ! To ?

Note: The init should be done in a place before there's a posibility of anyone accessing it. Maybe on viewDidLoad...